# How to override equality in a base class?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, type-erasure

I need something like:

```
trait Base {
  override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = other match {
    case that: this.type => true
    case _ => false
  }
}

case class Derived() extends Base
```

However, it seems `this.type` is the wrong way to pattern match here, because

```
val x = Derived()
val y = Derived()
x == y  //always false
```

will always yield false. Is it possible to overide equals in a base class for all derived classes (perhaps through using ClassTag or TypeTag), or must it always be defined in the derived class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
trait Base {
  type DerivedType <: Base
  implicit def tag: ClassTag[DerivedType]

  override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = validateType(other)

  def validateType(other: Any): Boolean = other match {
    case that: DerivedType => doSomethingAndReturnBoolean(that)
    case _ => false
  }
}

case class Derived() extends Base {
  type DerivedType = Derived
  override val tag = reflect.classTag[DerivedType]
}
```

Comment: This solution gives the warning "The outer reference in this type test cannot be checked at run time" on `case that: DerivedType => ...`, but I believe this actually works in my favor, since the type of `Base` is utterly irrelevant at runtime. I suppressed with `DerivedType @unchecked`.

Answer (score 1):

`this.type` refers to a type of which `this` is the only allowed value, so `case that: this.type` is equivalent to `case that if that == this`. `this.type` does not refer to the class of `this`.

You can use reflection to define `equals` in `Base`:

```
override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = other.getClass == getClass
```

However, without reflection, you will have to define `equals` in each subclass.